# Same app id for both F-Connect and FB Canvas app

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, policy, facebook-canvas

Recently FB changed their policy and according to that:

> a. Desktop web games off of Facebook.com may only use Facebook Login (Authentication, excluding user connections such as friend list), Social Plugins and publishing (e.g., Feed Dialog, Stream Publish, or Open Graph). When authenticating, these games may not request additional permissions other than age, email, and our Publishing Permissions.
>
> b. Games on Facebook.com and mobile must not share the same app ID with desktop web games off of Facebook.com. You must not use Canvas apps to promote or link to game sites off of Facebook, and must not use emails obtained from us to promote or link to desktop web games off of Facebook.com.

I do have a FB game and that time when I got a developer notice, I had created separate app for F-connect and FB Canvas app. Still in my game as I am linking user data using FB user id, on game play it never caused an issue. But at same time, if a user who registered via FB Canvas later try to use F Connect to play game, then he has to go through oAuth stuff again. So I am trying to understand, that can I use same app id for both F-Connect and FB Canvas app, given that both of them are exactly same app.